# AWUS036NHA Wireless Network Adapter random shutdown

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10-v1607, usb-network-adapter

I've recently bought an **AWUS036NHA USB** **Wireless Network Adapter** for my Windows 10 64-bit PC and I've found myself in a recurring problem. Sometimes the Network Adapter seems to shutdown: the WiFi is disconnected, and the blue light on the device start slowly blinking like there's no connection. It usually happens when I'm downloading at full connection speed (about 800Kb/s).

I've also noticed that merely **changing the USB Port** used by the Adapter fixes the problem for a little while. 
I've also unchecked the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" option in the Adapter settings. That almost fixed the problem, until today when it happened again.

What could it be?

Comment: Erratic performance from your wireless network adapter may have been because it is damaged or faulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's a USB 2.0 device it seems to require more than 500 mA, so you need a USB Y cable (similar to one for an external hard drive) or a powered USB hub.

I had the same issue until I realized it was a question of power requirements. The new cable completely solved the problem for me.